# Retrieving database column using JSON

Tags: php, json

I have a database consist of 4 columns (id-symbol-name-contractnumber). All 4 columns with their data are being displayed on the user interface using JSON.

There is a function which is responisble to add new column to the database e.g (countrycode).

The coulmn is added successfully to the database BUT not able to show the new added coulmn in the user interface.

Below is my code that is displaying the columns.

What is the problem?

**table.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // prepare the data
    var theme = getDemoTheme();

    var source =
    {
        datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
                 { name: 'id' },
                 { name: 'symbol' },
                 { name: 'name' },

                 { name: 'contractnumber' }
            ],
        url: 'data.php',
        filter: function()
        {
            // update the grid and send a request to the server.
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'filter');
        },
        cache: false
    };      
    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

    // initialize jqxGrid
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
    {       
        source: dataAdapter,
        width: 670,
        theme: theme,
        showfilterrow: true,
        filterable: true,
        columns: [
            { text: 'id', datafield: 'id', width: 200 },
            { text: 'symbol', datafield: 'symbol', width: 200 },
            { text: 'name', datafield: 'name', width: 100 },
            { text: 'contractnumber', filtertype: 'list', datafield: 'contractnumber' }
        ]
    });
    });
</script>
       </head>
           <body class='default'>
        <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
        </div>
            </body>
       </html>
```

**data.php**

```
     <?php
       #Include the db.php file
          include('db.php');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM pricelist";

      $result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
      $orders = array();
     // get data and store in a json array
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      $pricelist[] = array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'symbol' => $row['symbol'],
    'name' => $row['name'],

    'contractnumber' => $row['contractnumber']

  );
 }

    echo json_encode($pricelist);
  ?>
```